# Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ in psql execution from perl script

Tags: postgresql, perl, psql

I'm using following command in perl script to execute sql statement:

```
my $cmd = "PGPASSWORD=$pw  /usr/bin/psql  -h ${host} -p ${port} -d ${dbname} -U ${user} -c '${dropTblsSql}' -q  >> logfile.log"
my $out = `$cmd`;
```

The sql statement is contained in the `$dropTblSql` variable:

```
my $dropTblsSql = "
DO $$
 DECLARE 
  r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN SELECT quote_ident(tablename) AS tablename, quote_ident(schemaname) AS schemaname FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'rbm_pu7_mdt'
   LOOP
     EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I.%I CASCADE', r.schemaname, r.tablename);
   END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
";
```

The executions of the sql statement fails with `Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$` error. I tried escaping the dollar sings (`\$\$`), replace them with the single quotes (and double other single quotes). The only thing that works, is opening the statement from file (`-f path_to_file`), but I would like to avoid that option if possible.

Would anybody know how to solve the double dollar quoted string issue?

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to use the DBI module. Rather than having to juggle shell commands with difficult string interpolations.

Comment: The code you showed produces a string without any `$` in it, so it couldn't possibly have resulted in the error you claimed it resulted in. (Note that `$$` gets replaced with the process's PID in double-quoted strings.) Please show the code you actually ran!

Comment: 1. You show the password to everyone on the machine. 2. You have quoting issues with the Perl literal. 3. You have serious code injection bugs when you build your shell command.

Comment: @JimGarrison [*The optional `LANGUAGE` clause can be written either before or after the code block.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement probably gets cut off at the singe quote inside it. Try replacing those with named dollar quotes:

```bash
my $dropTblsSql = '
DO $do_block$
 DECLARE 
  r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN SELECT quote_ident(tablename) AS tablename, quote_ident(schemaname) AS schemaname FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = $abc$rbm_pu7_mdt$abc$
   LOOP
     EXECUTE format(
               $dynamic_sql$
               DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I.%I CASCADE
               $dynamic_sql$
              , r.schemaname, r.tablename);
   END LOOP;
END;
$do_block$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
';
```

As pointed out by ikegami, you might prefer to use [`PGPASSFILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) and point the utility to the right path instead of exposing `PGPASSWORD`.

Comment: @Zegarekhank you, indeed it helped, but I had to escape the dollar signs first (eg. `\$dynamic_sql$\`)

Comment: @JanFi86 What if you replace outer double quotes with singles to prevent interpolation?